# Python AwkwardArray: How to define a cyclic array?

Tags: python, numpy, awkward-array

I have been searching for a way to create a:

- Bounded
- Cyclic
- Contiguous
- numpyable API'ed

array.

I came across [AwkwardArray](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-array), but was not able to make sense of the [doc](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-array), which is very verbose, but unindexed for my term.

I would like to define an array and use it, just like I would a deque [with numpy API, using shape]

```
from collections import deque

d = deque(maxlen=10)
for i in range(20):
    d.append(i)

assert d.shape[0] == 10
```

I don't want a deque because it it a doubly linked list which is slow for slicing.

**How to do this with AwkwardArray, with contiguous memory?**

Comment: What do you mean by "numpyable API'ed"?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica np.functions should be able to work on above `d`, as if it were a np.array. `d.shape` is the most basic.

Comment: I could forego this requirement if I have to, but I much prefer not to.